# help me with xpath please

Tags: xml, xpath, html-parser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [if you know xpath then please help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287283/if-you-know-xpath-then-please-help)

hi, 
so here is the html code

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
Test
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>
<a href = "google.com">
Google
</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> test1</td>
<td> 
<a href = "yahoo.com"> Yahoo!</a>
</td>
</tr>


</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

so now I want the text Google and Yahoo!

how can I get that

here is what I wrote

```
table[1]/tr[1]/td[2]
```

I dont't know what is happening but nothing is showing up...

thanks

Comment: Please do not ask duplicate questions. Edit your original question to improve it instead.

Comment: @John Saunders: I agree. But we should close one, not both...

Comment: The 2 questions refer to different structures and there is a unique point in both answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath you are looking for is as follows:

For Google

```
/html/body/table/tr[2]/td/a/text()
```

For Yahoo

```
/html/body/table/tr[3]/td/a/text()
```

As the title is contained in a 'a' element and you use the text() node type test to get the text value of the 'a' element.

Actually I think your html has a additional `</tr>` at the bottom which makes it invalid

Comment: `text()` is not a function but but a node type test. And it's not a good idea to select text nodes in a mixed content model like XHTML...

Comment: understood, I have edited the answer regarding describing text() as function, however do you have an alternative to text(), it does answer the question regarding the content that was asked

Comment: If the result must be a node set, then the proper way is to select those `a` elements and then to get their string value by the proper DOM method. If the result can be just one node' string value, then you could use the `string()` XPath's function.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will always be that number and type of elements:

```
/html/body/table/tr/td/a/
```

A more generic way is:

```
html//a
```

Comment: Assuming your HTML doc is valid XML, which in this case it is. In general make sure you're using XHTML.